# Отсутствуют разделы реестре

Tags: реестр

У меня нет раздела `Layers` в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags`. Как можно это исправить? Создать и чтобы работал? Вообще у меня многих разделов нет, ощущение, что они типа с атрибутами `hidden`.  Либо у меня версия Windows такая, что раньше она была у людей и они про разделы писали, которые в моей версии убрали.
Версия Windows 1809

Comment: Укажите версию Windows.

Comment: @Fox вот версия 1809

Comment: Может быть этот раздел создается тогда, когда у вас есть хотя бы 1 программа, которая должна запускаться со специфическими настройками?

Comment: Может быть. Просто винду установил месяц назад. Вполне возможно, что я устанавливал мало приложении. Может быть вы знаете, как такой файл создать ?